# Best practices for testing a React modal with React Testing Library and Mock Service Worker?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

If I were building a simple function that divided one number by another, I would:

1. In all cases, call the function. The first test would probably be a happy path, like `10 / 2`.
2. Another test would divide a smaller number by a larger one, resulting in a decimal value.
3. Some other tests would introduce negative numbers into the mix.
4. Finally, I would be sure to have one test that divided by zero, to see how that was handled.

I have a series of modals in React that I need to test.  They have some commonalities:

1. They receive a set of props.
2. They act on those props to display a bunch of elements to the user, pre-populating these elements with some combination of the data in the props.
3. They use the `fireEvent.###` functions to simulate what the user would do within the modal.
4. Near the end of each test that involves a POST or a PATCH, a `Submit` button is pressed.
5. After pressing the `Submit` button, I have two `expect` functions at the end of each test, like in these examples:

```
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
  type: 'SOME_ACTION',
  payload: {
    property1: 'Some value',
    property2: 'Some other value',
    property3: 53.2
  },
});
```

This approach entirely makes sense to me because, much like a simple math function, the modal has data coming in and data going out.  But some colleagues are insisting that we shouldn't be testing with such `expect(spy)` functions.  Instead they're saying that we should test the end result on the page.  But there is no "page" because the modal is being tested in isolation, which I also believe to be a best practice.

Another suggestion was to add a success or failure string to a Mock Service Worker (MSW) response string, like "You've successfully saved the new data".  The reason I don't like this approach is because:

1. Such a string is just an artificial construct in the test, so what does it really prove?
2. If there are calculations involved with what is sent by the POST or PATCH, don't we want to know whether the correct data is being sent?  For example, if the user was prompted to enter the number of hours they worked each day in the past week, wouldn't we want to compare what was entered into the `input` elements vs. what was sent?  And maybe those hours are summed (for some reason) and included in another property that was included - wouldn't we want to confirm that the correct sum was sent?

I do respect the opinions of my colleagues but have yet to hear anything from them that justifies dropping the approach I've employed and adopting one of their alternates.  So I'm seeking insight from the community to better understand if this is a practice you would follow ... or not.

Comment: Your approach is sound as far as testing the form as an isolated unit, that's how I would have tested it myself. You could, however, have additional integration/end-to-end tests that actually test the behaviour of submitting a form as part of a page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case by case scenario with no real answer, as performance and other variables may play a role in making these decisions.

However, based off the information you give both you and your team are right. You would want to validate that the correct data is being sent to the backend yet you would also want to validate that the user is receiving a visual response, such as "Successfully saved data".

Yet if I have to choose one it would be the checking the **data as that has the most "code coverage"**. Checking for the "success" message simply checks if the submit button was pressed where as the data checking assures that most, if not all, data states were correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do both.

> But there is no "page" because the modal is being tested in isolation, which I also believe to be a best practice.

I like doing this because for more complex components, TDD with unit tests keep me sane. Sometimes I build out the unit test just to make sure everything is working, then delete it once the integration tests are up. (Because too much unit tests can be a maintenance burden).

Ultimately I prefer integration tests over unit tests because I've experienced situations wherein my unit tests were passing, but once the component's been nested 3 levels deep, it starts to break. Kent Dodds has an [excellent article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/write-tests) on it.

My favorite takeaway from the article:

> It doesn't matter if your component `<A />` renders component `<B />` with props `c` and `d` if component `<B />` actually breaks if prop `e` is not supplied. So while having some unit tests to verify these pieces work in isolation isn't a bad thing, it doesn't do you any good if you don't also verify that they work together properly. And you'll find that by testing that they work together properly, you often don't need to bother testing them in isolation.

Comment: `neldeles`, in some sense I agree with you but with a caveat.  Say that Parent P spawns Modal M.  Imagine you have 10 tests for M, many of which are edge cases.  And with the tests for P you have 1 test just to see if M is launched properly.

6 months lapse and then another developer is assigned to make some changes to M.  With the tests for M in the test file that they are, it would be quite obvious to them where they should add tests.  If the detailed tests for M were in the test file for P, I strongly suspect that they would not.